# Emitir eventos desde modulo Nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs

un saludo, estoy tratando de emitir un evento en nodejs desde un modulo aparte, pero no logro capturarlo, tengo este codigo en el modulo

```
var util = require("util");
var events = require("events");

function MyStream (connection) {

if (!(this instanceof MyStream))
    return new MyStream(connection);
  events.EventEmitter.call(this); 

  var self = this;
  self.emit('pulse', 'client pulse');     

}

util.inherits(MyStream, events.EventEmitter);

exports.MyStream = MyStream;
```

y luego desde el script principal intento capturar el evento pero no logro capturarlo

```
var server = require("./server");

var mystream = server.MyStream('aqui van los parametros');

mystream.on('pulse', function  (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

tampoco estoy obteniendo ningún error, ¿alguna idea?
gracias

Comment: Dónde emites el evento `join`?

Comment: Si, tenia un error al copiar el código aquí, ya lo actualice, estoy emitiendo es el evento `pulse`

Comment: Cuando devuelves `new MyStream()` el código debajo no se ejecuta. Deberías cambiar la forma en la que emites el evento `pulse`.

Comment: Es cierto, el método MyStream debería ser llamado como una función? `var mystream = server.MyStream(function(connection))`

Comment: Devolver una instancia de MyStream y con esa instancia hacer un `emit`, no dentro del constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes dos problemas en tu código

1. Los nombres de los eventos no coinciden. Por un lado emites un evento **pulse** y por el otro intentas capturar el evento **join**. En lugar de:

   ```
   self.emit('pulse', ....
   ........
   mystream.on('join', ....
   ```

   Debería ser

   ```
   self.emit('pulse', ....
   ........
   mystream.on('pulse', ....
   ```

   Los nombres de los eventos que se emiten y capturan deben coincidir.
2. Estas intentando emitir el evento dentro del mismo constructor del objeto. Esto causará que cuando termines el setup de tu event handler el evento ya se habrá emitido y tu código no lo capturará de todas formas.

   ```
   var mystream = server.MyStream('aqui van los parametros');
   // Cuando llegas a esta línea de código ya el evento se ha emitido
   mystream.on('join', ..........
   ```

   Para probar este punto sólo establece un timeout dentro del constructor de tu objeto y verás emitirse el evento sin problemas. Este es un reemplazo para tu fichero *server.js*

   ```
   function MyStream (connection) {
       // Es una buena práctica ponerle llaves a todos tus bloques aunque sean de una sola línea
       // Lee http://jshint.com/docs/options/#curly
       if (!(this instanceof MyStream)) {
           return new MyStream(connection);
       }
       events.EventEmitter.call(this);

       var self = this;

       // Este código es sólamente para una demostración
       setTimeout(function () {
           self.emit('pulse', 'client pulse');
       }, 3000);
   }
   ```

   Y para el otro fichero

   ```
    var server = require("./server");

    var mystream = server.MyStream('aqui van los parametros');

    mystream.on('pulse', function  (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
   ```

   Y el resultado se muestra en la foto

   [image: evento]

Comment: Si, ya había editado la primera parte, cierto.. el evento se emitía pero no podía capturarlo de esa forma, gracias por tu respuesta, seguiré probando como emitirlo desde otra función, la tomare como valida.